# Synchronized block and variable scope

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Can anyone explain to me how the parameter map will be affected in the following code if two threads access it at the same time.  Is the map exposed to thread safety issues because it is not inside the synchronized block?

```
public void fun(String type, String name, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
    parameters.put(Constants.PARM_TYPE, type);
    parameters.put(Constants.PARM_NAME, name);
    try {
        synchronized (launcher) {
            launcher.launch(type, bool, parameters);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("AHHHHH, the world has ended!",e);
    }
}
```

I have looked at the following but I'm still questioning it: [Synchronized and the scope of visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329064/synchronized-and-the-scope-of-visibility)

Comment: yes, if that map is not thread-safe, all kinds of bad things can happen.

Comment: What you need is a BlockingMap implementation.

Comment: @alexg what is a `BlockingMap`? Did you mean a `ConcurrentMap`?

Comment: `parameters` rock'n'roll, that will happen.

Comment: @MattBall Yes I did :)

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you sending the same `parameters` instance from multiple threads as a parameter? If not, all of the answer below are based on wrong assumptions.

Comment: So the parameters map is a separate instance in each thread so the values in the map should be fine I do believe.  I believe the issue here would be the scope of the synchronization.  I am debating on whether or not to make the method synchronized or keep it at the block level.  It seems to me that even if the method parameters are unique to the thread that there could still be an issue at run time when executing this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `parameters` instances are separate **(as you mentioned in your last comment)**, then there is no problem with this code.

The method parameters - besides `Map parameters` -  are just 2 `String`s, so there are no synchronisation issues regarding them.

To put the `synchronized` block onto method level or on `launcher`: They're different objects. If you put on method, it will synchronize on `this`, otherwise on `launcher`. Since you want to protect the 'launcher', you have to "build the fence" as close as you can - so synchronizing on `launcher` is OK.

There is another technique which is using a `Object lockObject = new Object()`, and does the synchronization on that object, but for this purpuse I think it's overkill, but you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple threads have a handle to the same `parameters` instance and they call this method (which modifies the map) with a non-thread-safe map implementation, all kinds of bad things can/will happen (e.g. map corruption which may/may not manifest itself as exceptions like NullPointerException).

Comment: Please be specific, what kind of exceptions. That's not a specific answer.

Comment: @GaborSch -  i was specific.  "(e.g. map corruption)".  there may not even _be_ an exception.  please don't vote on answers you don't understand.

Comment: But there may be even Exceptions. In this sense, even a `ConcurrentModificationException` can happen. So, your answer is as wrong as my answer was - so far.

Comment: @GaborSch - sure, there may be exceptions.  you could get random NullPointerExceptions, or other stuff.  if you think my answer is factually incorrect fine.  if you are just being spiteful, please remove your downvote.

Comment: @GaborSch - and no, there won't be CMEs cause those are only thrown during iteration (which isn't happening here).

Comment: I would, but I can't, it's locked. And honestly, I'm not convinced with the "all kinds of bad things" answer.

Comment: @GaborSch - i don't need to "convince" you.  like i said, if i'm wrong, fine.  otherwise, i'd suggest reading up a bit more on the subject before downvoting answers you don't understand.  just because i haven't "convinced" you doesn't make my answer wrong.  (edited so you can fix your vote).

Comment: OK, undownvoted for your favor. I have read enough, I have experience in threading environment, but I may be wrong sometimes, so I deleted my answer (still holding that CME is the most common issue with maps, although we cannot see here the other parts of the code).

Comment: Now it's your turn to accept that others can have different opinions, different points of view. And yes, you have to convince me next time **professionally** that your answer is useful. By now I think that it is a balloon, and there's not much inside.

Comment: @GaborSch - again, you have yet to identify something _wrong_ with my answer...  if you read the link at the end of JohnVint's answer you'll get one very detailed example of how HashMap can get corrupted (there are many more).  differing opinions are fine, but you haven't yet given any backing to your opinion that corruption _won't_ happen (or whatever your opinion is).

Comment: I didn't say that this answer was wrong. I said that this answer is way far not complete. And that's an opinion, and people vote based on their opinion. That's it. BTW, if you have read the last comment on question, you can see that **all of the answers were based on wrong assumptions**. So, both of us were wrong :)

Comment: @GaborSch - heh, yeah, i was wondering that about the original question as well.  i did clarify that assumption in the beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine if you had a shared Map.

```
private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
```

that is being updated by many threads as displayed in your example.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        fun("a","b", map);
    }
}).start();
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        fun("a","b", map);
    }
}).start();
```

Each thread may update the map at the same time which could lead to [A Beautiful Race Condition](http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming multiple threads are accessing the method `fun()`, the way map works is if you insert the same key multiple times then the value of that key would be overridden each time. But this might not be the only problem. There could be race conditions and corruption issues too. If you want an implicitly thread safe data structure, I assume a `HashTable` will get your job done.

Answer (score 0):

if more than one thread executes that code concurrently passing the same object as the parameter map then you will have a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software).

This will definitely cause thread safety issues unless you:

- use the right Map implementation, based on your requirements and the Map implementation concurrent behavior ([ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) for instance, but this depends a lot on the actual requirements for your app)
- or write thread safe code yourself (probably using synchronization primitives like 'synchronized').

**IMPORTANT:** Please notice that just moving the lines of code that modify the map into the synchronized block won't necessarily remove the race condition as you'll have to consider which other threads in your app may try to modify the map and which object they will use to synchronize their access to it. The code in the function is using a reference to 'launcher' to synchronize. Any other thread modifying the map without synchronization or with synchronization over an object different than 'launcher' will cause a race condition