# Are actions in a synchronized block visible to other threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

I have read this [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329064/synchronized-and-the-scope-of-visibility) and the answer help a lot, but there is still a question.

I heard that changes of shared fields in a synchronized block is guaranteed visible to other threads.

For codes like this:

Thread1:

```
synchronized(lock) {
   obj.field1 = value1;
}
```

Thread2:

```
synchronized(lock) {
   System.out.println(obj.field1);
}
```

Assuming thread1 precedes thread2, it is said that according to the Java Specification, it may go like this:

```
hb(write to obj.field1 in threadOne, unlock in threadOne) AND 
hb(unlock in threadOne, lock in threadTwo) AND 
hb(lock in threadTwo, read from obj.field in threadTwo)
```

hb stands for happens-before in Java Specification, and it guaranteed the visibility.

And because " If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z) ", we get:

```
hb(write to obj.field1 in threadOne, read from obj.field1 in threadTwo)
```

My question is on the first line:

```
hb(write to obj.field1 in threadOne, unlock in threadOne)
```

In Java Specification, I only found:

> An unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock
>   actions on m (where "subsequent" is defined according to the
>   synchronization order).

That indicates the unlock action happens-before subsequent lock actions. But I cannot find words like:

> An action in synchronized block happens-before the unlock action.

So is it correct? And where can I find it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All actions of the same thread are ordered by the happens-before relation.

JLS 17.4.5:

> If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).

Also note, that happens-before is transitive, thus if the write within the synchronized block happens before unlock, and unlock happens before a lock on another thread, then the write happens before any action in the synchronized block in the other thread.

Comment: Thank you! That's just what I want. While I still have a question, as for the intra-thread semantics, JLS said "The actions of each thread in isolation must behave as governed by the semantics of that thread" , but the unlock action seems unnecessary to be ordered after the actions in block. As the intra-thread semantics is just tested in a single thread, even ignoring the unlock action would not cause a problem. Would you tell me more about it?

Comment: @LucienEvans then unlock action needs to be ordered precisely to get the transitive order for your two threads. A single thread doesn't even notice that it unlocked.

Comment: @LucienEvans I don't see a contradiction. The definition of hb is as it is, it simply orders all operations within a single thread. Of course in a single threaded application you could reorder unlock with any other operation, and I guess that's still theoretically possible. JVM could detect that there is only a single thread running and not only reorder lock and unlock, but even completely remove them.

Comment: "An implementation is free to produce any code it likes, as long as all resulting executions of a program produce a result that can be predicted by the memory model." This means that the definition of hb only tells what is the expected behaviour, and does not force the compiler/JVM to execute operations strictly in the order of hb. If there is no observable difference, the JVM can execute code in an order that is not complaint with the hb.

Comment: @ciamej exactly. As a practical example, if Escape Analysis can prove that an object is purely local, i.e. there can not be a subsequent lock action by any other thread, all effects of locking and unlocking on the object will be removed. This happens in real life.

Comment: While, I understand now. My question may be strange that I used to think that the intra-thread semantics is just tested in a single thread environment, while it doesn't. It is actually tested in each thread of a multithread environment.

Comment: Thanks very much for answering my question,. It is very kind of all of you.

Comment: @LucienEvans "intra-thread semantics" is just what it says, things only relevant to a particular thread. Each thread has its own view of the world. Relevance to different threads only comes into play as part of the specification cited in this answer. I don't know what you mean with the word "tested" here.

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation here is that unlock action has a happens-before edge with the last action in the thread. It's called program order.
It's described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3)

`Among all the inter-thread actions performed by each thread t, the program order of t is a total order that reflects the order in which these actions would be performed according to the intra-thread semantics of t.`

Comment: Thank you very much, it does help. But for the intra-thread semantics, JLS said "The actions of each thread in isolation must behave as governed by the semantics of that thread" , but the unlock action seems unnecessary to be ordered after the actions in block. As the intra-thread semantics is just tested in a single thread, even ignoring the unlock action would not cause a problem. Would you tell me more about it?